# What is the c# equivalent of context.fail(response)?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm seeing a lot of examples for node.js to fail a lambda using context.fail(response).

What is the c# equivalent of context.fail(response) since the ILambdaContext for c# doesn't have fail or succeed methods on it?

Comment: I think the C# equivalent is to throw an exception. No exception == success.

Comment: A bit of a correction: the `context.fail(error)` is used for the [old node.js api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html#nodejs-prog-model-oldruntime-context-methods). The [new node.js api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html) uses a callback model. Now to answer the question: [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-exceptions.html) states how to handle function errors in C#.

Comment: Throwing an exception worked, I needed to tie in the regex on the integration response, but I was able to get it to 500, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Node.js version 0.10.42 runtime the context contained methods for `succeed`, `fail`, and `done`[1]. This model was replaced with a callback model which removed the methods from the context and errors are passed from a callback[2].

In the C# programming model the analogous is to throw an exception[3].

From the docs:

> When an exception occurs in your Lambda function, Lambda will report
>   the exception information back to you. Exceptions can occur in two
>   different places:
>
> - Initialization (Lambda loading your code, validating the handler string, and creating an instance of your class if it is non-static).
> - The Lambda function invocation.

An example is given where an exception is thrown from a Handler:

> ```
> namespace Example {            
>    public class AccountAlreadyExistsException : Exception {
>       public AccountAlreadyExistsException(String message) :
>          base(message) {
>       }
>    }
> } 
>
> namespace Example {
>    public class Handler {
>      public static void CreateAccount() {
>        throw new AccountAlreadyExistsException("Account is in use!");
>      }
>    }
> }
> ```

[1]: [Using Earlier Node.js Runtime (v0.10.42)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html#nodejs-prog-model-oldruntime-context-methods)

[2]: [Function Errors (Node.js)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html)

[3]: [Function Errors (C#)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-exceptions.html)

Comment: There's a little bit more involved here than throwing an exception, I also needed to create a method response status code and an integration response with a regex linking to the status code.

Comment: @RandomUs1r Hi can you please provide a detailed answer with code. I've been struggling to get proper error codes from C# lambda integrated with API gateway. Please see this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085211/how-to-get-proper-http-status-codes-from-amazon-api-gateway-integrated-with-c-sh